# errors in admin area after updating to joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

I updated my joomla site to 2.5 from joomla 1.7 I faced below errors:

1- I cannot open global configuration page from the admin area and receive "500 internal server error"
2- When I press the add new article button from the admin area I receive the same error.
3- When I press the add new category button from the admin area I receive the same error.

appreciate if you can help to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was about to go crazy (even considered switching to another CMS) ... the problem appears to be related to the fact that Joomla 2.5 is throwing several errors and the PHP engine was trying to write to the php_errors.log file in a directory where it didn't have write permissions, thus the 500 error (misleading I know).

Incidentally, this happened to me on a Windows box running IIS 7.5, not Apache.  The solution, intiailly was to edit my PHP.INI file and change the "error_log" setting to point to a folder which had write permissions for all websites.  I just created a new folder and gave the 'users' group modify permissions - not the best way to do it but for development purposes, it was ok.

You then have to restart IIS.
It is important that you actually restart IIS, not just restart the application pool, as this didnt seem to force PHP to re-read the config.

Once I got this far, I started noticing errors (which I will continue to post here among other places until I can find a solution).  So far, the first error I see is when I go to add a New Menu Item, i get this:

```
Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(\metadata.xml) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:\Inetpub\vhosts\myWebsite.com\httpdocs\) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\myWebsite.com\httpdocs\libraries\joomla\filesystem\file.php on line 523
```

It appears that Joomla is trying to verify if the \metadata.xml file exists, however I'm not sure where that file is or what it does.  At this point, i suspect it's still ultimately a permissions problem, but I'm still digging...

Comment: Hey! I got the same warning about metadata.xml. Have you fix it already or just swithed it off?

Answer (score 0):

1. The most common cause of 500 error that I've seen on Joomla! websites is related to the permissions of the files on the website. eg. yesterday we had to fix a website for a company that had upgraded and in the process somehow set the Group `write` permission on their `/administrator` directory.

   You can check this quickly through the file manager of your hosting service, if using CPanel you should make sure your directories are set to `755` (*User has read/write/execute permissions, Group and World have read permission*) and files set to `644` (*User has read & write permissions, Group and World have read permission*).
2. These sound like the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

See this rundown of potential upgrade problems by Brian Teeman:

http://brian.teeman.net/joomla-1.7/upgrading-to-joomla-2.5-some-warnings.html

The problem you are having could be related to the database issue he mentions.